# Terrain Ruggedness Index (TRI) calculated in QGIS is approx 4 times that calculated in GDAL

Tags: qgis, terrain

When I calculate TRI using QGIS and GDAL tools for the same elevation DEM, I get results that are comparable between the two except that the absolute values in QGIS are approximately 4x that in GDAL. I am not modifying any defaults.

Can anyone shed light on what may be going on?

Which set of TRI values may I trust?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: By default QGIS uses approximate statistics for styling. Could you set the style's min and max limits to "Actual (slower)" and see if there still is a difference?

Comment: No difference. I ran zonal statistics and am getting the same 4x results as illustrated by the legend that is shown in the question.

Comment: Use SAGA GIS software.

Comment: That may be an alternative solution, thank you, but I would like to better understand what is going on with the two programs I have cited in my question.

Answer (score 3):

I cross-tested the TRI results in QGIS and GDAL by sampling a few cells using the equations in Riley et al (1999). The QGIS results are spot on, the GDAL results are smaller by orders of magnitude. Still not sure what is going on, but I now know that the QGIS calculations of TRI are reliable, the GDAL are not. Hopefully this will be useful to others.

Edit: After filing a bug report for GDAL, it turns out that GDAL uses the TRI formulation for **bathymetric** terrain analysis based on Wilson et al 2007 instead of the more commonly used formulation for TRI for above-water terrain analysis.
https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/3320

Comment: I compared the output of QGIS to the ones I got from the raster package in R. The QGIS output is the same as from R - they use the math from Wilson et al. 2007 see here for details: http://search.r-project.org/library/raster/html/terrain.html - the output I got from the GDALdem from the Raster menu in QGIS was also four times lower and the pattern looked inverted. There must be something wrong with that module.

Comment: Interesting! Please file a bug at https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues